# How to execute function when parameter is array or callable?

Tags: php, arrays, function, closures, callable

Look this example code:

I'm getting the error:

> **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type Closure as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\dermaquality\test.php:11 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\dermaquality\test.php(20): test(Object(Closure)) #1 {main} thrown in**

```
$array = array(
    'hello' => function() {
        echo "HEllo world";
    }
);

function test( $func )
{
    if (is_callable( $func['hello'] )) {
        $func['hello']();
    }
    else {
        $func();
    }
}

echo "Executing 1 <br/>";
test( $hello = function() {"Hello world";} );
echo "Executing 2 <br/>";
test( $array['hello'] );
exit;
```

How can I call `$func` if `$func` is function or if `$func['hello']` is function?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to change the if to do the reverse: if (is_callable($func)) $func; else $func['hello']();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in `if (is_callable( $func['hello'] )) {` because you dont know if `$func` is an array.. btw you dont put array as parameter in `test( $array['hello'] );` you put just function...

```
function test( $func )
{
    if (is_callable($func)) {
        $func();
    }
    else if (is_array($func)){
        if(isset($func['hello']) && is_callable($func['hello'])){
            $func['hello']();
        }else{
            // unknown what to call
        }
    }else{
        // unknown what to call
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great but I don't understand what's the difference between check first with `is_array`, how `is_callable` knows that is_array was called?

Comment: `is_callable` is just function, never know if another was called or not, in first `is_callable($func)` is not important what value is in variable `$func` because function `is_callable` will check if its callable, before you use `$func['hello']` you must know that `$func` is an array thats why

Comment: just the value of variable will pass to function throught parameter, so `some_function([]);` is the same as `$array = []; some_function($array);` in context of the function

Comment: when you write `$func['hello']` you read value of array `$func` with key `hello`, if `$func` is not array then error will occur

Comment: just try something like `$string = 'test'; $string[0];` or `$array = ['test']; echo $array;` or `$array = ['test']; $array['whatever'];` all of them will fail...

Comment: that means the type of value is important for functions because they know how to handle only that types for which they are prepared to work

Comment: btw you could use this: `function test((array) $array){}` and error will trigger when you try to pass value which is not an array